# How to reduce size of bubble wraps?

Tags: packaging, garage, recycling, waste

Big ones are too voluminous to throw away; a single wrap could fill up a whole garbage bag.

Any quick and/or handy way to "shrink" it?

I tried

- to pop each bubble with fingers *over hours/days*
- to stomp on it: at least better than the former, no fun

I have no kids around to have fun with them.

Comment: I bet there are plenty of kids to help you waiting at the closest playground or daycare centre. It should be easy to reward a child with this wonderful "toy." But, stick around to take the shreds to recycle properly for your municipality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking about using some kind of [wire brush](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ExNsW_iRDKHm6ASJiIvoDw&q=sharp+wire+brush&oq=wire+brush) or [metal curry comb](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1696&bih=829&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=khdsW5r_CKzi6AS5mKBI&q=metal+curry+comb).

There are some wire brushes in the shape of cylinder that you could simply bowl on that bubble wrap. If brush is sharp enough it should perforate the bubbles.

Please note that I've never tested that "lifehack" so it's just a guess.

Answer (score 5):

Discard it as is. Roll it up and secure it with some string or tape.

Don't bother to put it into another piece of plastic (the bag) which adds to the plastic pollution of the planet.

Alternately, run a sharp knife down each of the rows of bubbles. Even cutting every-other row will decrease the volume significantly.

Is there a UPS store or FedEx outlet nearby? (There is.) Donate the bubble pack to them for re-use. They'll appreciate the savings and you'll have reduced the need for additional bubble wrap by a bit which helps all of us.

Comment: I love the donation idea.  It's very true, they are very happy to receive the donation.  For small amounts, you can also recycle bubble wrap along with old plastic bags by depositing in the special receptacle for this purpose at the entrance to grocery stores and big box stores (e.g. Walmart) [in the U.S. at least].